# Unable to call a method while defining an instance directly

Tags: java, class, format

I am new to Java and was trying to use the `getCurrencyInstance()` and `format()` methods from the `NumberFormat` class.

I cannot understand why this works:

```
NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
System.out.println("US: " + us.format(payment));
```

But this doesn't work:

```
NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(payment);
System.out.println("US: " + us);
```

Any ideas as to why it works like this?

Comment: Because `format()` does not return a `NumberFormat`.

Comment: For the Beginner stage, it is to use IDE which will give an error messages and most of them are self-explanatory also while using the methods it is advisable to know about its return type

Answer (score 0):

The format method you are calling in this line `NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(payment);` does not return a `NumberFormat` object, it returns a `String` object. Your code is trying to store that `String` object in a `NumberFormat` object which would give you a compilation error. To fix it you could change that line to `String us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(payment);` This should give you the output you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

`format()` returns a `String`, not a `NumberFormat`, so

```
String us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(payment);
System.out.println("US: " + us);
```